# How do you use Babel without the .babelrc or any "special" config files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I would like to use `@babel/core` purely in JavaScript, and configure all the babel plugins and presets in JavaScript, so I don't need any `.babelrc` or other special config files. How do I do this?

I see this:

```
babel.transform('code', { plugins, presets })
```

But I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with that...

Note, I am using Webpack too, if that makes a difference. Does babel just need to fit in with the Webpack build somehow, or does it standalone? I would also like to use Babel in Node, so both on the frontend and backend.

Comment: For webpack - there is https://github.com/babel/babel-loader. This all you need... You can configure the plugins etc in the loader configuration.

Comment: How about for node?

Comment: I always assumed: Same concepts, seperate config file and `target: 'node',` in your webpack config.